# Why public/image is not rendered in NextJS when published to GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, github-pages

Using `absolute path` in `img src` solves my problem, but the reason causing original problem is unknown.

I add a custom prefix to NEXT routing, and I didn't use `NEXT/IMG` to render profile photo. I guess it's the reason why `img src` attribute doesn't change according to Next path prefix config.

---

**Original Question**

I am creating my first [online portfolio](https://yumingchang1991.github.io/personal-portfolio/) using Next + React, and then published to github pages. There is one photo in the portfolio homepage.

- When I first visit the page, the photo rendered correctly
- but if navigate to other same-site pages, and then would like to visit homepage again by clicking site logo, which is a Next/Link point back to home page. The photo is not rendered
- there is a floating button on bottom-right corner using the same photo, it always rendered correctly
- [Github Repo](https://github.com/yumingchang1991/personal-portfolio): main branch is the active branch
- warning: my code is definitely structured horribly. It might hurt your eyes ...

---

my profile picture is named Avatar.png stored in public folder

this is where the code is returning my profile photo

```
// components/about.js
<div className={styles['avatar-container']}>
    <img className={styles['avatar-img']} src='Avatar.png' width="188px" height="196px" alt="a picture of Yu-Ming"></img>
</div>

// about.js is a react component imported to pages/index.js
```

---

I notice that there is additional '/' appended to the end of url when first visit

- first visit: https://yumingchang1991.github.io/personal-portfolio/
- same-site navigation then link back: https://yumingchang1991.github.io/personal-portfolio

---

Currently, I have a workaround is to make about.js to become a standalone page. (although I don't feel like to do so ...)

Comment: Use `src="./Avatar.png"` instead. Although I don't know what happened actually...

Comment: @BigLiao Thanks for suggestions. `src="./Avatar.png"` doesn't work for my case. I add prefix to NEXT routing path, so using `"./Avatar.png"` doesn't capture img directory correctly. Good news is that you DO remind me that I could try `absolute path`, and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for people who encounter similar problem: use **absolute path** instead of relative path will solve this problem. However, I haven't figured the reason why this problem comes up at first place.

more details:

- I add basePath in `next.config.js`

  **next.config.js**

  ```
   const nextConfig={
       ...
       basePath: '/personal-portfolio'
   }
  ```
- When this Next project deployed to gitHub, this is the `img src` rendered

  ```
  // Relative Path

  // 1st visit
  img src = 'https://yumingchang1991.github.io/personal-portfolio/ProfileLarge.png'

  // subsequent visits when navigating to other pages and comeback to root
  img src = 'https://yumingchang1991.github.io/ProfileLarge.png'

  // subsequent visit does not add basePath correctly
  // so changing from Relative URL to Absolute URL fix the problem
  ```